# The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. But it works on similar code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

In my controller I am searching the database for specific records in an association table.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int picId, int myOtherId)
{
    var itemToEdit =
        db.AssocationTable.Single(
            x => x.PropertyId == picId && x.MyForeignKey == myOtherId);

     var myRecord = db.TestTableOne.Find(itemToEdit.PropertyId);

    var lstOfIntsINeed =
        db.AssocationTable.Where(
                x => x.PropertyId == picId && x.MyForeignKey != myOtherId)
            .Select(x => x.MyForeignKey.Value)
            .ToList();

    // the list above, if nothing is found, will give me an empty list where Count == 0
}
```

Now I am doing the **SAME EXACT** code but for a different property and I am receiving:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Here is my code for that:

```
public ActionResult MyOtherAction(int picId, int myOtherId)
{
    var itemToEdit =
        db.AssociationTable.Single(
            x => x.PropertyId == picId && x.MyOtherForeignKey == myOtherId);

    var myMainRecord = db.TestTableOne.Find(itemToEdit.PropertyId);

    var lstOfIntsINeed =
        db.AssociationTable.Where(
                x => x.PropertyId == picId && x.MyOtherForeignKey != myOtherId)
            .Select(x => x.MyOtherForeignKey.Value)
            .ToList();
}
```

In both my database and my Domain Model Class for my Association Table both `MyForeignKey` and `MyOtherForeignKey` are nullable:

```
    [ForeignKey("TestTableTwo")]
    public int? MyForeignKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TestTableThree")]
    public int? MyOtherForeignKey { get; set; }
```

So, my question.. why in the first ActionResult is the lst receiving a count of 0 (which is what I expect), and the second ActionResult is receiving the exception error?

Comment: What line do you get that exception on?

Comment: @maccettura In the 2nd ActionResult.. `var lstOfIntsINeed...`

Comment: Can you add the definitions of the `AssocationTable`?  I'm thinking that `PICTrainingId` is looking suspect, but can't prove it.

Comment: @Trevor sorry, just edited my question.  That should've been `PropertyId`

Comment: If `MyForeignKey` and `MyOtherForeignKey` are nullable int, why are you going straight to `.Value` inside your `Select()` method.  If that code was run  in .NET, it could throw a `Nullable Value must have a Value` exception, but as it's converted to SQL, I'm not sure what you'd get if the Key was null.  It's possible that the only reason the first query doesn't fail is because it returns no records to process.

Comment: I need the Values of those nullable ints to be put into a `List<int>` to be used in another method that accepts a parameter of `List<int>`.. if there are zero records, then it needs to return me an empty list with a count of 0

Comment: Ok, but your `MyOtherForeignKey` is a nullable int, what are expecting the code to do if it encounters a `null` `MyOtherForeignKey`?  It can't put that into a `List<int>`.  Why not try `x.MyOtherForeignKey != myOtherId && x.MyOtherForeignKey != null`?

Comment: @Trevor Okay, that worked but in reference to what you said... `MyForeignKey` is also a nullable int and I'm not explicitly checking for nulls like what you suggested, and it works as expected. So why for this one I have to explicitly check for nulls?

Comment: I imagine the first one only works because in your tests it returns no values, so it never needs to actually try to fit a `null` into an `int`.  I think the code ultimately has the same problem.  I'll word it up into answer for others, you can accept if it turns out to be right :)

Comment: So you think I should check for nulls in each scenario then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `.Value` on your `nullable int` without checking it for `null` first.  Ultimately it means you are performing a narrowing implicit conversion in the middle of the query.

If the code were to be run in .NET, and the `x.MyOtherForeignKey` was null, it would throw a `Nullable object must have a value` exception.  In this case, the code is being converted into a Linq-to-Sql expression and run in EntityFramework.  I think it's finding a null `x.MyOtherForeignKey` in your second query and giving this exception.

Depending on what you want the code to do when it encounters a `null`, you could change it to filter out the `nulls`:

```
var lstOfIntsINeed =
    db.AssociationTable.Where(
            x => x.PropertyId == picId && x.MyOtherForeignKey != myOtherId && x.MyOtherForeignKey != null)
        .Select(x => x.MyOtherForeignKey.Value)
        .ToList();
```

... or to replace the null with a default value.

I think the same problem exists in your first query as well, and the only reason that it didn't fail in your tests is because the query returns no entries (or more specifically, no entries with a `null` `MyForeignKey`), so it hasn't failed.

Given that you've defined `MyForeignKey` as nullable, you must be considering a situation where it is null, so it would be sensible to fix it in that query too.

You could test to see if this was the case by changing the `.Where()` clause to deliberately return AssociationTable entries with null values.

Hope this helps